# Can I use 2 Navigation mode in actionbar?

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to use `ActionBarSherlock`, I need implement 2 navigation mode

`NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST` and `NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS`

My code

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

But, I can't use both, just  the last one. In this case mode tabs

How I can use both at once?

Answer (score 1):

> How I can use both at once?

You can't. There is only one navigation mode for the action bar at a time.

You might consider switching to `ViewPager` and a tab-style pager indicator (e.g., `PagerTabStrip`), and use that for your tabs.

Comment: Ty, only one mode of navigation.I will try to implement what you say. NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST and viewpager